# installing anaconda for multiple users on fedora

Tags: anaconda, fedora

I follow the instructions given here [link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/). I can successfully instal anaconda but only for the root user. The other users can't use it.

My OS is fedora 31. The location of the folder anaconda is "/anaconda", that is, the folder is at same level of bin, home, etc. What can I do to install for all the users?

Thanks

Comment: You can create a virtual  environment for users.

Comment: you mean create virtual environment for users from my status as root user? That partially solves the problem, but ideally I would like the users to create their own virtual envinronments and manages everything themselves.

Comment: Yes as root user you implement básic or  standard environment.  A good tool is virtualenvwrapper . You can create virtual env by project (shared by a team or per user) https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts.html#scripts